# Bootstrap multiselect refresh or rebuild does not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect, jquery-ui-multiselect

I want to bind my multiselect with ajax but after ajax call items does not show.I try rebuild or refresh multiselect but it still does not show

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         var categCheck = $('#multiselect').multiselect({
             includeSelectAllOption: true,
             enableFiltering: true
         });


         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/Listpositions/")",
             success: function (data) {
                 $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                     alert(item.PositionName);
                     var opt = $('<option />', {
                         value: item.PID,
                         text: item.PositionName
                     });
                     opt.appendTo(categCheck);

                 });
             }
         });
         $('#multiselect').multiselect('rebuild');
         categCheck.multiselect('rebuild');

         categCheck.multiselect('refresh');
         $("select.multiselect").multiselect("refresh");
   });
        </script>
```

Here is my multiSelect page link:http://pratikisara.com/Home/Quick
[image: This is multiselect but it is empty]

How can I make ajax call from multiselect JS file([enter link description here](http://pratikisara.com/Content/js/MultiSelect/ui.multiselect.js)) and in which code block should I do ajax call?

Comment: are you using bootstrap multiselect or jquery ui multiselect? Please use proper tags?

Answer (score 3):

You need to to the rebuild and/or refresh in the AJAX success function. In your code, the AJAX call is made, then the multiselect is rebuild. But the rebuilt may happen before the AJAX call succeeds. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

     var categCheck = $('#multiselect').multiselect({
         includeSelectAllOption: true,
         enableFiltering: true
     });


     $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/Listpositions/")",
         success: function (data) {
             $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                 alert(item.PositionName);
                 var opt = $('<option />', {
                     value: item.PID,
                     text: item.PositionName
                 });
                 opt.appendTo(categCheck);

                 // Rebuild after adding the options!
                 $('#multiselect').multiselect('rebuild');
             });
         }
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> by using reload its working fine for me. multiselect("reload") function refresh checkbox list in ajax call.

```
var obj_ddl_ExistingIdea = $("#ddl_ExistingIdea");
        if (response.length > 0) {

            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var str_newOption = '';
                str_newOption = "<option value='" + response[i].IdeabookId + "'>" + response[i].Name + "</option>";
                obj_ddl_ExistingIdea.append(str_newOption);
            }
            obj_ddl_ExistingIdea.multiselect("reload"); //using reload its working for me
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sltHeadCountdetailsCategorySiteCode').empty();      
$("#sltHeadCountdetailsCategorySiteCode").multiselect('destroy');
```

Comment: This works fine for me after spending lot of time. sltHeadCountdetailsCategorySiteCode is my element id

Answer (score -1):

This Is  100% fine code....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var chkreport = $('#reporting_unit'); // Object creation for your dropdown

var ajaxpath = 'ajax/fend.php';
var ajaxUrl = baseUrl + ajaxpath;
$('#hospital_category').on('change', function() {
var hospital_id = this.value;
//alert(hospital_id);
$.ajax({
method: 'POST',
url: ajaxUrl,
data: {
perform_action: 'reporting_list',
hospital_id: hospital_id
},
dataType: 'html',
success: function(result) {

chkreport.append(result); // append option in the object created before ajax calling

// Now call multiselect function with their parameter
chkreport.multiselect({
columns: 1,
placeholder: 'Select Reporting Unit',
search: true,
selectAll: true
});

chkreport.multiselect('rebuild'); // it will reload dropdown need to create multiselect with checkbox option.
}
});

});

});
```